# How to cache Only http status 200 in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using `scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache.HttpCacheMiddleware` to cache scrapy requests. I'd like it to only cache if status is 200. Is that the default behavior? Or do I need to specify `HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES` to be everything *except* 200?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by default `HttpCacheMiddleware` run a `DummyPolicy` for the requests. It pretty much does nothing special on it's own so you need to set `HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES` to everything except 200.

[Here's the source for the DummyPolicy](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/extensions/httpcache.py#L18)
And these are the lines that actually matter:

```
class DummyPolicy(object):

    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.ignore_http_codes = [int(x) for x in settings.getlist('HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES')]

    def should_cache_response(self, response, request):
        return response.status not in self.ignore_http_codes
```

So in reality you can also extend this and override `should_cache_response()` to something that would check for `200` explicitly, i.e. `return response.status == 200` and then set it as your cache policy via [`HTTPCACHE_POLICY` setting](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=ignore_http_codes#httpcache-policy).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no, you do not need to do that.
You should write a CachePolicy and update settings.py to enable your policy
I put the CachePolicy class in the middlewares.py

```
from scrapy.extensions.httpcache import DummyPolicy

class CachePolicy(DummyPolicy):
   def should_cache_response(self, response, request):
       return response.status == 200
```

and then update the settings.py, append the following line

```
HTTPCACHE_POLICY = 'yourproject.middlewares.CachePolicy'
```